# I want to covert currency and I am using below function

Tags: php, json

I want to covert currency and I am using below function

```
function convertCurrency($amount, $from, $to){
    $url  = "https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to&meta=ei";
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    preg_match("/<span class=bld>(.*)<\/span>/",$data, $converted);
    $converted = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $converted[1]);
    return round($converted, 3);
}
```

But this function is not working for me and giving the below error:

Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=350&from=USD&to=YEN&meta=ei) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/hydra/public_html/recentportfolio/bookitla2/index.php on line 6

Please give me a quick solution for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527150/failed-to-open-stream-no-suitable-wrapper-could-be-found)

Comment: this same code working perfect on localhost and not working on server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the `PHP` configuration for following `allow_url_fopen` property.It should be true to allow user to fetch the content from URl.

Alternative, you can use `CURL` instead of `file_get_contents` because it's bit risky to allow that.You can also check this :

[Should I allow 'allow_url_fopen' in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127534/should-i-allow-allow-url-fopen-in-php)

Hope this will help you to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your server must have the [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) property set to true.

If you don't want to change your settings check [CURL](http://php.net/curl) library.