# How to access local drive's file from the server (www.domain.com)?

Tags: php

Needed to access the local hard disk drive from the server.

For example, one file name `ex.txt` is in D drive, by running the php script(named as:`run.php`) with `$file = fopen("D://ex.txt","r");` it will open the file in read mode.

It doesn't show error when its run on local server i.e `(localhost/run.php)`, file opens since the file gets accessed. and now the thing is I need to access the same local disk when the same `(run.php)` script runs on the remote server.

The script will be kept in `www.domain.com` i.e `(www.domain.com/run.php)`. Now after running `www.domain.com/run.php` it has to access the (local device sending the request) `D://ex.txt`.

Since PHP is a server side, thought Javascript can be used to access the `D://ex.txt` andn then send to server to do so the url will be `//home/user/D/ex.txt`. But the file should be accessed from `www.domain.com//`.

In what way this can be achieved. Tried in Google, after that only asking here. Any Info Plz,Thanks.

Since `run.php` kept inside public_html of `www.domain.com`. So fopen function path will take default as `domain.com/public_html` as the root. but i dont have to upload the file or copy the file... just i have to read few lines from the text file in D://ex.txt..... like--> www.domain.com is my website... then whichever user example like YOU access www.domain.com/run.php then the contents of YOUR Computer's D Drive's ex.txt has to be read n to be sent to the server...!!
 I m Talking about the two way mechanism where the local machine and the server has to be matched prior.... ex) can Your local machine be configured like my server www.domain.com access your local disk ??.... if your local machine allows my server to read then its fine.. in else case error message is ok... Because thinking about the Pendrive authentication for the web application to run.... You have a pendrive where encrypted data is present.. If you loginto my domain.com then i ll check ur Pendrive data for the correct (matching encrypted)data and give you permission to login.. and on each page navigation i check the users pendrive for the data... If the user removes the pendrive My Application on www.domain.com should not allow you to access the application.. Sorry About this big post.. because this is my First Question in Stackoverflow.. Thanks :)

Comment: Copy the file to the remote server.

Comment: why you are not moving file on server ( in public html folder and use it )

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to upload a file and do something with it. For that the user must elect to upload a file to you.  You can do this with `<input type="file">`.

Comment: Thanks all for ur replies.. but i dont have to upload the file or copy the file... just i have to read few lines from the text file in D://ex.txt..... like--> www.domain.com is my website... then whichever user example like YOU access www.domain.com/run.php then the contents of YOUR Computer's D Drive's ex.txt has to be read...!!

Comment: It is not possible. The file is not on your server, so the server cannot read it. Full stop. You need to upload it, period. As you said, you could do this partly in Javascript, but the user will have to explicitly choose the file from the disk regardless. **You cannot simply reach into someone's machine over the internet and read files!** Thank god.

Comment: Yea..Thats the twist is....  I m Talking about the two way mechanism where the local machine and the server has to be matched prior....  ex) can Your local machine be configured like my server www.domain.com access your local disk ??.... if your local machine allows my server to read then its fine.. in else case error message is ok... Because thinking about the Pendrive authentication for the web application to run....  You have a pendrive where encrypted data is present.. If you loginto my domain.com then i ll check ur Pendrive data for the correct data and give you permission to login..

Comment: . n plz read my last few lines of my questions... its edited now so.. Thnx :)

Comment: Write a browser plugin, there's no real other way. Or perhaps you're really looking for *client side SSL certificates*, which provide authentication via a locally stored secret.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. It's for security reasons.

To begin let's compare your website to a grocery store. You look for security on your website, and for this purpose you want to trespass any security barrier on your client's computer. A grocery store that behaves like your website has a security officer at the door, that asks every client to open his purse and counts the money, the he asks for the login of his bank account to look if he has money on his card, and finally he lets the client in to shop.

Would you like to go shopping in this grocery store? Probably not. The same way, nobody will connect to a website that requires access to his computer's local drive.

Now that you understand that you look into the wrong direction, here is a solution that gives such strong authentication like you are looking for :

Use SSL with a client certificate together with standard user authentication. A client certificate is a file that proofs the identity of the client computer. In addition of identifying the user by his login credentials, you identify the machine. This gives you the security you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

you can just make your Computer Accessible from the Public Internet
and on server side you can just include your computer localhost.
something like that:

> server side www.domain.com/run.php
>
> just include("public ip your local host/run.php @ localhost");
>   or if include doesnt work use "echo file_get_contents(public ip your local host/run.php @ localhost");"

it's my first time answering on stackoverflow and english is not my mother tongue.

[see here for include http](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

[see here for echo file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527150/failed-to-open-stream-no-suitable-wrapper-could-be-found)

hmm or maybe you can just allow www.domain.com from your firewall

Comment: "Just make your computer accessible from public internet..." – err, no. Just no.

Comment: he said "Needed to access the local hard disk drive from the server", is that any other option? could you please tell me. i am new in programming. sorry.

Comment: Protip: people do not always understand what they ask for. Giving them terrible advice in return does nobody any good. See my comments under the question.

Comment: thanks for protip. and can you just give your answer or solution or you can edit mine beside give "no"

Comment: I would if there was a clear answer. As it is this question cannot reasonably be answered. Sometimes the correct answer is to send the asker back to the drawing board and have them figure out what they actually want.