# PHP file_get_contents not working from CRON

Tags: php, cron, file-get-contents

I'm using PHP with a CRON job to get the contents of a URL using:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");
```

I then use this content to send as an HTML newsletter. I'm running PHP 7, and I have enabled the relevant PHP INI settings:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

However, the $content variable is still turning up empty and my error_log is showing the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.example.com): 
failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found 
in /home/xxxx/public_html/cron.php on line xxx
```

Everything else in the cron.php is working as expected.

Additionally if I manually visit the cron.php via a browser, file_get_contents is working perfectly.

Running WHM/cPanel etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you setting that php.ini option? It's possible that there are two different php.ini files: one for use from requests from the web browser, and one for use for running PHP scripts from the command line (which your cronjob would be doing).

Comment: Via WHM's MultiPHP Manager and Multi INI Manager. In both the New Multi PHP Manager and the soon to be deprecated Manager, they both have the setting enabled. Additionally, I'm calling the CRON job by declaring the cron.php via /usr/local/bin/ea-php70 to ensure it's using the correct version of PHP.

Comment: You could be right though. I wonder if I can output phpinfo somehow as CRON?

Comment: Hmm, I unfortunately don't know much about WHM. I would ask your hosting provider about the possibility of a separate php.ini for CLI. You could also try to use the curl extension instead? See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-curl/ for an example of fetching a page with curl.

Comment: That's a good point, you could also try to print out phpinfo() from a cron script and see what that says.

Comment: Upon further reading, looks like you can manually declare a .ini file if desired (towards the bottom): https://help.whmcs.com/m/automation/l/969680-identifying-the-php-ini-used-for-in-command-line-cron-engine

Comment: Found it - the ini file CRON was using had it disabled! Legend. I'll test then answer my own question. Thank you @thatoddmailbox

Comment: Great, glad to hear you could figure it out!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527150/failed-to-open-stream-no-suitable-wrapper-could-be-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get path to php.ini in you script:

```
php_ini_loaded_file();
```

set path to php.ini:

```
/opt/php/7.3/bin/php -c /var/www/u1234567/php-bin/php.ini -f /var/www/u1234567/public_html/site.com/script.php
```

Comment: Check php.ini: `php -i` or `ini_get()` (https://www.php.net/ini_get).

Comment: Thank you. This is what I’m going to try shortly. Hopefully manually declaring the specific edited INI file will do the trick. Many thanks!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt this worked. I ran php -i, confirmed the ini file and then manually declared that in my cron job using -c. Thanks guys :)